# Switching DB Context in LINQ Entity Framework asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In laravel they have eloquent that can change between databases.

For example:

```
$db = (statement) ? "mysql1" : "mysql2" ;

$users = DB::connection($db)   
              ->select(...);
```

How do you do you do this in LINQ?

```
Model data =  (from table in context_db <--- how to i dynamically change this?? 
               .Model
               where table.ref_no == ref_no
               select new Model
                      {
                             ...
                      });
```

my web.config contextdb

```
 <add name="DBContext1" connectionString=" ... / >
 <add name="DBContext2" connectionString=" ... / >
```

Comment: What do you mean? @UsmanKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by editing your ContextDB constructor.

first you have to set a connection string on your web.config

```
 <add name="DBContext1" connectionString=" ... / >
 <add name="DBContext2" connectionString=" ... / >
```

second on your contextdb constructor add a parameter for your connection.

```
public partial class YourContextDB: DbContext
{
        public YourContextDB(string connection = "name=DBContext1")
            : base(connection )
        {
        }
        ... //basically ur models below
}
```

3rd
you can now do this.

```
string connection = (statement) ? "name=DBContext2" : "name=DBContext1";
YourContextDB dbcontext = new YourContextDB(connection); //default is "name=DBContext1"

Model data =  (from table in dbcontext <--- dynamic dbcontext
               .Model
               where table.ref_no == ref_no
               select new Model
               {
                ...
               });
```

NOTE: you cannot use code-first `Update-Database` with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your another DbContext in services, in `ConfigureServices` method in **Startup.cs** and pass it to your constructor of your class like:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContextA>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));
```

**YourClass.cs (or YourClass.cshtml.cs)**

```
public class YourClass
{
        private readonly YourDbContext _context;

        public CreateModel(YourDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
 }
```

You can register multiple `DbContext` objects in services and can pass multiple `DbContext` objects to your `constructor`.

Later you can switch between your dbContextes:

```
 private DbContext getDbContext(bool statement)
 {
     if(statement)
       return _dbcontext1;
     else if(statement2)
       return _dbcontext2;
     else
       return _someOtherDbContext;
 }



private void foo()
{
 Model data =  (from table in getDbContext(statement)
               where table.ref_no == ref_no
               select new Model
                      {
                             ...
                      });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input. do you have link or referece that can elaborate the solution? it is kinda sketchy in my part. do you mean i should make another helper for the switching between context?

Comment: There is some good description about using DbContex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: Not sure this answers his question.

Comment: @koviroli seems like i cant add the AddDbContext on my startup.cs. im missing a dependency and i cant figure out what. im using mvc 5. not .net core. thank you for updating your answer.